# Alternative to wall clock time

Tags: python, linux, performance, runtime, performance-testing

I developed an algorithm and measured the wall clock time. When reporting my results, I would like to take into account the speed of my computer. How can I measure the speed of my computer and then divide/multiply such, that when other people can also measure the speed of their computer and then multiply/divide they get a rough estimate for how long it will take for them. How can I do this, how can I approach this issue?

For the context of this question, please assume I cannot re-run the experiments. On the other hand I do not need a very precise results: I am just looking for ball-park numbers. A simple "please do these two steps to get the speed of your PC and then divide/multiply by this number" is close enough. Anything more would be unacceptable for my counterparts. Thus I am looking more for a pragmatic than an academic solution.

In case it is important: I wrote my program with Python 3 in PyCharm and I am on a Linux machine (Kubuntu 20.04).

Comment: That's what big-O notation is for. It ignores any *constant* factors (including those due to hardware differences) in the running time, focusing only on how the time changes with input size.

Comment: Why don't you just measure how long your algorithm takes for a known fixed, representative input?

Comment: @chepner: I am already reporting this. I want the aspect of the runtime constants additionally - just with a bit more independent measurement values than wall time. I don't expect anything super exact, but a ball-park estimate would be good for the "other guys with the other computers".

Comment: @MattTimmermans: That is what I am doing. Now, the other guys will get my data and then they want to know how long it will take to run my program on their computer. Sure, they can just run the program. But let's assume that they either they don't want to (e.g. they don't have the time/manpower or are lazy ;-)), or they want to see if my claims are correct and test their results against my claims. In the second case eye-balling should be fine in my context.

Comment: I believe the suggestion is "run a smaller, representative example, then use that to extrapolate how long the full job will take"